# ¿Imagen de portada ocupe el 100% de la pantalla en móvil y escritorio?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, aplicación-web

Estoy tratando de hacer una pagina web en donde se utiliza un carrusel de bootstrap para tener varias imágenes de portada pero quisiera que ocupen el 100% de la pantalla tanto de altura como ancho en móvil y en escritorio, he intentado varias cosas pero no he podido ya que la imagen o se estira de mas o no se reajusta a la pantalla...

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Gracias!

Comment: Media querys, son muy faciles de usar y super potentes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El tamaño del carousel se da por el tamaño de las imagenes, por lo que puedes ajustar el tamaño de estas usando:

```
.carousel-item img{
   object-fit: cover;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

Este es un ejemplo basado en Bootstrap 4.5 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/carousel/#example

```css
#carouselExample .carousel-item img{
   object-fit: cover;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div >
<div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x480.png" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x490.png" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x495.png" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Gracias! En su momento encontre otra solución pero esto me ayudo para una nueva aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

podrías mostrar el codigo html y css que le tienes al carrusel?
intenta poniendole un

```
width: 100%;
```